# ImageIO exception cannot read my input file. For the buffered Image when reading file

Tags: java, image

```
public FinalProject() throws IOException
     {
        String fontType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What kind of font would you like? "); 
        String backgroundColor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like your background color to be blue, green or pink?");
        if(backgroundColor.equals("blue"))
        {
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("calculator_back_and_keypad.png")));
        }
        else if(backgroundColor.equals("pink"))
        {
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("calculator_back_and_keypad2.png")));
        }
         else if(backgroundColor.equals("green"))
        {
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("calculator_back_and_keypad3.png")));
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(c, "Sorry color not recognized so color was set to the defalut (blue)");
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("calculator_back_and_keypad.png")));
        }
        Font font = new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, 30);
        txt = new JTextField(13); //create a text field
        Color color = new Color(255,0,0);
        txt.setForeground(color);
        txt.setFont(font);
        c = getContentPane();

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        c.add(txt);

        buttons = new HashMap <String, JButton>();

        String[] names = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","x","/","sin","cos","tan","arcsin","arccos","arctan","log","abs","sqrt","exp","M","M Recall","C","="};
        for (String d: names)
        {
            BufferedImage pic1 = ImageIO.read(new File("button1.jpg"));
            JButton i = new JButton(new ImageIcon(pic1));
            i.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
            c.add(i);
            i.addActionListener(this);
            buttons.put(d, i);
        }
```

?the ImageIO is saying that it is unable to read the file and the file is inside the folder
already.
            setSize(400,650);
            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(false);
            txt.setEditable(false);

Comment: 1) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: `BufferedImage pic1 = ImageIO.read(new File("button1.jpg"));` By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment I think you have to use [`ImageIO.#read(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) method. Also Why are you doing same thing in the for loop?

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource/button1.jpg");
BufferedImage pic1 = ImageIO.read(url);
JButton i = new JButton(new ImageIcon(pic1));
i.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
c.add(i);
i.addActionListener(this);
```

this should be done outside the for loop and in the for loop

```
String[] names = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","x","/","sin","cos","tan","arcsin","arccos","arctan","log","abs","sqrt","exp","M","M Recall","C","="};
for (String d : names)
{
    buttons.put(d, i);
}
```